# How to convert a list of dictionaries into a csv?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, which I want to export to a csv. The format of the list is as follows:

```
dict_list=[{'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Telecom', 'Score':105},
           {'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Banking', 'Score':145}]
```

I want the keys to take the column names, and values as each row. Can someone help me with how to do it.

Expected Output:

```
Country    Industry    Score
US         Telecom     105
US         Banking     145
```

Comment: The [standard csv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) have an example of this exact case. You gotta do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the csv library

```
import csv

dict_list=[{'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Telecom', 'Score':105},
           {'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Banking', 'Score':145}]



with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Country', 'Industry', 'Score']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')

    writer.writeheader()
    for d in dict_list:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Or more compactly.

```
with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Country', 'Industry', 'Score']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dict_list)
```

*plus: Assuming that each element in the list contains all the corresponding elements we can use the following code to obtain the header. Thanks @martineau*

```
fieldnames = dict_list[0].keys()
```

Comment: `writer.writerows((dct for dct in dict_list))`

Comment: You can use the list directly because it is an iterable: `writer.writerows(dict_list)`

Comment: You could also use `fieldnames = list(dict_list[0].keys())` and not hardcode them (although you would lose some control over their order).

Comment: Thanks @martineau, but it is not necessary to use list since it accepts the parameter iterables.

Comment: Thanks. The first line gave syntax error. So I changed it to

`with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
>>> df
  Country Industry  Score
0      US  Telecom    105
1      US  Banking    145
>>> pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df, 'test.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Here is have given `sep` aregument as comma, you can use as per your wish.

```
Beagle:~ kumarshubham$ cat test.csv
Country,Industry,Score
US,Telecom,105
US,Banking,145
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  
dict_list=[{'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Telecom', 'Score':105},{'Country':'US', 'Industry':'Banking', 'Score':145}]  
df= pd.DataFrame(dict_list)  
df.set_index('Country').to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: You could improve your question by giving a brief explanation